# rendering array at page load in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array that I would like to render at page load. In my code below it fires in the code block when I push a new array item.

Is there a way to take part of the code where I loop through the array and put it in a function, and call that function when the page loads, and then call it back whenever I push a new array item.

This is the HTML code:

```
<h1>Todos</h1>
 <form action="" id="addTodo">
 <input type="text" name="inputTodo" placeholder="Insert new todo">
 <button>Add Todo</button> 
 </form>
 <input id="search-todo" type="text" placeholder="Search todo">
 <button id="reset-search" type="reset" value="reset" onclick="window.location.reload()">New search</button>

 <div id="todos"></div>
 <script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

and this is my js code:

```
const todos = [{
  text: 'Order airline tickets',
  completed: false
},{
  text: 'Vaccine appointment',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'Order Visa',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'Book hotell',
  completed: false
}, {
  text: 'Book taxi to airport',
  completed: true
}]

//Insert new todo
document.querySelector('#addTodo').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    newTodo = document.querySelector('[name="inputTodo"]').value;
    todos.push({text: newTodo, completed: false});
    console.log(todos)

    //show the whole array
todos.forEach(function (todo,) {
  const p = document.createElement('p')
  p.textContent = todo.text
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(p)

  let radio_button_true = document.createElement("INPUT") // Creating input tag for true button
  radio_button_true.setAttribute("type", "radio")

  let radio_button_false = document.createElement("INPUT") // Creating input tag for false button
  radio_button_false.setAttribute("type", "radio")

//create variable to generate random id for radiobutton
  const id = Math.random().toString(36)

  radio_button_true.setAttribute("name", id)
  radio_button_false.setAttribute("name", id)

  //Switch loop over the completed
  switch (todo.completed) {
    case true:
      radio_button_true.setAttribute("checked", "true") // Mark true button as checked
      break
    case false:
      radio_button_false.setAttribute("checked", "true") // Mark false button as checked
      break
    default:
      break
  }

  document.body.appendChild(radio_button_true) // Appending true radio button to body

  let radio_button_true_node = document.createElement("span")
  let radio_button_true_text = document.createTextNode("true") // Creating span text with true
  radio_button_true_node.appendChild(radio_button_true_text)
  document.body.appendChild(radio_button_true_node)

  document.body.appendChild(radio_button_false) // Appending false radio button to body

  let radio_button_false_node = document.createElement("span")
  let radio_button_false_text = document.createTextNode("false") // Creating span text with false
  radio_button_false_node.appendChild(radio_button_false_text)
  document.body.appendChild(radio_button_false_node)

})

const notDone = todos.filter(function (todo) {
  return !todo.completed
})

const summary = document.createElement('h2')
summary.textContent = `You have a total of ${notDone.length} todos pending`
document.querySelector('#addTodo').appendChild(summary)

})

//contains the search text
const filters = {
  searchText: ''
}

//Function that takes in the notes object and the search text as parameters
const renderTodos = function (todos, filters) {

  //use filter method for the title search string and save it to filters variable
    const filteredTodos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
        return todo.text.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase())
    })

    const notDone = filteredTodos.filter(function (todo) {
      return !todo.completed
    })

    //Empty the div containg the result, this has to be between filter and the display of the result
    document.querySelector('#todos').innerHTML = ''

    const summary = document.createElement('h4')
    summary.textContent = `You found ${notDone.length} hit${notDone.length !== 1 ? 's' : ''} on this search that is not complete`
    document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(summary)



    //loop through note object, create a p tag for the title searched and append to the div
    filteredTodos.forEach(function (todo) {
      const noteEl = document.createElement('p');
      noteEl.textContent = todo.text;
      if (!todo.completed) {
          noteEl.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      }
      document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(noteEl);
  })
    elem = document.createElement("hr")
    document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(elem)
}

document.querySelector('#search-todo').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  filters.searchText = e.target.value
  renderTodos(todos, filters)
})
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The below code fires a function just after page load. You can put your array function inside this.

```
window.onload = function() {
  the_function_you_need_to_call(param1, param2);
};
```

for part II-

```
condition_after_which_you_push_data_in_array
{
array.push();
the_function_you_need_to_call(param1, param2);

}
```

Comment: A bit of an explanation would be helpful... For example, what's the purpose of [`array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) with no parameters?